# I want to define an element with javascript and tell it to do something for me using onclick

Tags: javascript

I want to solve the function is not define problem:

**Error:** Uncaught ReferenceError: addHandler is not defined     at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```
const showProduct = (products) => {
  start();
  leftContainer.innerHTML = "";
  const addHandler = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
  };
  products.forEach((product) => {
    const title = shortenText(`${product.title}`);
    leftContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="main__product" data-category="${product.category}">
            <div class="product__feedback">
                <span class="feedback__rating">${product.rating.rate}<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="feedback__visitor">${product.rating.count}<i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="${product.image}" alt="" class="product-image__img">
            </div>
            <h3 class="product__title">${title}</h3>
            <div class="product__condition">
                <span class="condition__price">$ ${product.price}</span>
                <button class="condition__link" onclick="addHandler(${product.id})">Buy <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
  });
};
const addHandler = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
};
```

Comment: `onclick` attributes work in the global scope (one reason they are awful and should not be used).

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) to listen for events and [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) instead of function arguments.

Comment: [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is a better choice than `innerHTML =+` since it doesn't disrupt the state of elements that are already there.